# Why the screenshot of the fragment is black?

Tags: android, fragment, screenshot

Why the screenshot with this code are black?

```
    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.todayfragment);
    Bitmap screenshot = Bitmap.createBitmap(vg.getWidth(), vg.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    vg.draw(new Canvas(screenshot));
    String path = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), screenshot, "Photo to share", null);
```

Comment: We have no idea what is in the `ViewGroup`.

Answer (score 0):

because you never drew anything in the bitmap. So color `#000` is black.